# Converting DataFrame to GeoDataFrame with Polygon

Tags: python, convert, geopandas, data-frame, geodataframe

I would like to convert my `DataFrame` to `GeoDataFrame`, but every post is about points. I need to convert polygons. Coordinates are in `df['geometry']`. How can I do that?

My DataFrame is below:

I was trying:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
```

But I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: 495495.84 516704.74 495487.95 516706.54 495490.65 516718.33 495498.54 516716.52 495495.84 516704.74
```

[image]

Comment: The figure is unreadable, try to write the results. What have you tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed.

Comment: I don't know how to start.

Comment: I'am getting error "shapely.errors.WKTReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`geometry` column is not in WKT format. Therefore you need a custom method similar to `geopandas.point_from_xy`. You can use the following script. `polygons_from_custom_xy_string` method is string-specific.

In case of the `geometry` column has different XY string (for example `'x y, x y, ..'`), you should modify `s.split()` in `xy_list_from_string` method.

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def polygons_from_custom_xy_string(df_column):
    
    def chunks(lst, n):
        for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
            yield lst[i:i + n]
    
    def xy_list_from_string(s):
        # 'x y x y ...' -> [[x, y], [x, y], ...]
        return list(chunks([float(i) for i in s.split()], 2))
    
    def poly(s):
        """ returns shapely polygon from point list"""
        ps = xy_list_from_string(s)
        return Polygon([[p[0], p[1]] for p in ps])

    polygons = [poly(r) for r in df_column]

    return polygons


df = pd.read_csv("file/path")

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=polygons_from_custom_xy_string(df["geometry"]))

gdf.plot()
```